# Django save a list of items in a m2m intermediary table

Tags: django, forms, model, m2m

I have a m2m field in a class, and a through table. I am not table to save the list of items from the through table.
if i have a multi select form, like below, and i want to be able to save all the selected items, how should i do it??

My model form looks like this:

```
class ClassroomForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
          model = Classroom
          fields = ['classname','members','private']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                creator = kwargs.pop('user')
  super(ClassroomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  relations = Relations.objects.filter(initiated_by = creator)
  self.fields["members"].queryset = \
       User.objects.filter(pk__in=[r.follow.pk for r in relations])
```

and my save method like this:

```
def save_classroom(request):
   classroom_instance = Classroom()
   if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClassroomForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user = request.user) 
        if form.is_valid():
           new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
           new_obj.user = request.user 
           new_obj.save()
           membership = Membership(member = HERE SELECTED ITEMS FROM FORM,classroom=new_obj)

           membership.save()
```

How this can be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Django should handle many-to-many ModelForms just as any other model form.

> When you use a simple save() on a form, all data -- including many-to-many data -- is saved without the need for any additional method calls.

Reference:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: i have to save data in the intermediary 'through' table. That's why i am trying to initialise it. Otherwise, i get an error like: Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use Membership's Manager instead.

Comment: @dana Did you manage to fix it?